# Different batch file with same command not working

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have 2 batch files both having the same content. One runs perfectly fine and the other one just crashes on opening.

The only difference is that I created one on the same machine and copied the other one from different machine.

Comment: And, do we have to guess what is inside the batch file or how it crashes? Just to bet, check file encoding

Comment: @MCND thanks for your input. I realised that posting the batch file content would be of no use.

Answer (score 0):

An emailed/downloaded file often needs to be `unblocked` in modern windows.
Right click the file and check the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. As the contents of the file were generated via code, there were issues with its encoding. Thus changing the encoding to ASCII solved the issue.